# How to have proper highlighting for HTML within templates with Sublime Text 3

Tags: javascript, html, templates, sublimetext3, highlight

So I have sublime text 3, I think I need to modify the file `HTML.sublime-syntax` to make the IDE parse the inside of `<script type="text/template">` as HTML instead of javascript.

I saw some post about editing the file but it was for sublime text 2 and this does not work anymore.

This is what my file look like: https://pastebin.com/azVjvUr5

Comment: it looks like ST already parses the contents of `<script type="text/template">` as HTML...

Comment: yes. I was actually using `HTML (twig)` for the file instead of `HTML`